# Jumping between open splits using gF?

Tags: split

Im trying to make a setup where I can

1. open a vertical split, preferably in the `/tmp/` directory in readonly mode(so you cannot write changes)
2. read the shell output from a linter/compiler (in my case, the program `shellcheck`)
3. if required perform a substitution on all the file/line number information to bring to the form : `filename:line` which allows `gF` to jump to that file and line.

This way my aim is to jump from the split containing the error info to the one containing my code where I can make the changes and jump back and move to the next occurance of `file:line` and jump back and so on...

So far I have the following and it works in bringing up the split and all the error info:

```
 function! BashLint()
         let curr=expand('%:p')
         vert sview /tmp/%.lint
         exe "0read ! shellcheck -f gcc " . curr
         %s/In \(.*\) line \([0-9]\+\):/\1:\2/e
         norm gg
         exe "normal " . "/" . curr . "/e+1\<cR>"
 endfunction
```

This works but I cannot jump in between the splits as pressing `gF` simply opens the file/linenumber in a **new tab**. Is there something I can do about this ? I thought about remapping `gF` but I don't know how I could approach doing something like that ?
Any thoughts / suggestions to make this better would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a compiler plugin allows you to supplement the `:make` command to run any tool you want, and parse the output into the quickfix window. In your case, I would so something like the following:

```
" ~/.vim/compiler/shellcheck.vim
if exists('current_compiler')
  finish
endif
let current_compiler = 'shellcheck'

if exists(':CompilerSet') != 2
  command -nargs=* CompilerSet setlocal <args>
endif

CompilerSet makeprg=shellcheck\ -f\ gcc

CompilerSet errorformat=%f:%l:%c:\ %t%.%#: %m
```

Change to shellcheck with `:compiler shellcheck`.

Then `:make %` (or `:make -options -and any other files*`) and use the goodies in `:help quickfix` to navigate.

---

[ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) can do something similar automatically. [It does its own parsing](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/557a1ed5da70cb443a8650766f4e8ea95e8c0da3/autoload/ale/handlers/shellcheck.vim#L51) in many cases, which I think is a bug (re-use the errorformat tool! Argh!), but it works well for many tools.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use the quickfix window. I only had moderate success with it in python, but it was all configured by a plugin. I also tried a bit with latex files. I never tried to set up vim for bash, so I don't know any plugin.